# removing or modifying a selected number of users or mailboxes in powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I've been trying to remove a selected number of users or mailboxes in powershell. I have created a CSV file and imported it into a variable $userz . : (XYZ as my specific domain name)

```
$userz = (Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\v-remogh\Desktop\Reza\userz.csv).userprincipalname
Userprincipalname
Reza2@XYZ.com
Reza5@XYZ.com
```

Since the variable becomes an array, this command doesnt work:

```
Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $userz
```

I tried to make a loop but dont know how exactly should refer to variable $userz.

```
Get-User | foreach {Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName -eq $userz}
```

**1**- Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $userz

Error : "Remove-MsolUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'UserPrincipalName'. Specified method is not supported."

**2**- Get-User | foreach {Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName -eq $userz}

Error: "foreach : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the `$userz` variable, not the outpub of `Get-User` in this case.

Try:

```
foreach($u in $userz){
    Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $u
}
```

Comment: I also found : Import-Csv -Path \userz.csv | foreach { Remove-MsolUser -userprincipalname $_.u}